# Externalizing static content from a WAR and serve both on jetty

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, resources, jetty, packaging

In my project I use Maven to package a web application to a WAR which is later deployed to Jetty using a custom Maven plugin on CentOS. The custom plugin is used by every project that deployes to a production environment. There is now a requirement that all static content (like web site text, properties) is packed outside of the WAR so that it can be changed in production without requiring a new release cycle. I am unsure how to achieve this externalization.

The Jetty server has the directory structure described in [Jetty quick start guide](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quick-start-getting-started.html). Currently, the web application already offers *some* `.properties` files which can be altered externally, and these reside in the `resources/` directory. These files are moved here by the custom Maven plugin. The WAR resides in the `webapp/` folder. One option for my problem is to use `<packagingExcludes>` of `maven-war-plugin` to not include e.g. `*.xhtml` and `*.properties` in the WAR. Later, I can use the custom Maven plugin to move excluded files to `resources/` directory. But, I have a feeling this is not the correct way to externalize static content... Shouldn't xhtml files live in `webapp/` folder while the only the properties file live in `resources/` folder?

I have also researched the option of deploying the WAR as exploded, but I am unsure of the implications of such. Clearly, the changes in the exploded WAR files will be overwritten in the next deploy, but the idea is to do static changes both in development and production. Also, I am not sure how to achieve WAR "explosion", is it something that Jetty does for your WAR if configured in `jetty.xml` or do I have to extract the WAR before deploying?

Lastly, how do people serve static content in Jetty which can be altered in production? Do both the WAR and static files live side by side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that you can add HTML tags to properties and later use `<h:outputFormat>` to fetch these properties with parameters. Also, you can do pretty neat stuff with property files as described in [MessageFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

My solution was to keep the `.xhtml` files inside the WAR, but use simple HTML snippets properties from the default resource bundle which is based on a `.properties` file. These properties were included in the `.xhtml` using `<h:outputFormat>`and `<h:outputText>`. This allows the user to add simple styling like bold and underline to the snippets.

The properties file are copied to the Jetty `resource` folder using the custom Maven plugin, so I have kept the `.properties` files in the WAR. For some reason the Jetty `resource` folder has precedence over the packed `.properties` files, so this works out fine. Also, as Akber pointed out, I will have the default versions of the properties available if for some reason the WAR was moved to some other application server where the `resource` folder is not available.

Of course, with this approach the code can break if malformed HTML is placed inside the snippet properties, as pointed out by Akber, but it works for our application as it is very small. I may never have done this if this was a much larger application, but then I might have gone for a database based solution for adding static text (like Joomla/Drupal/Wordpress).

Answer (score 1):

The Jetty `resources` folder should not be used for application files.  A J2EE web application (war) should be self-contained -- and in Jetty, reside only on the /webapps folder -- and its only binding to the container (Jetty servlet engine) is via the `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

Since property files may be read from the classpath and the Jetty `resources` folder is part of the system classpath, a property file there could be read by the web application class loader.  Note that there are other ways to read property files as well and the Jetty `resources` folder should not be used for application properties.  Also, the application may not be portable as other application servers have different forms of webapp classloader isolation.

If the below architecture approach does not work for you, then your only approach would be to expand (explode the war) in the /webapps folder and hope for the best when files are edited.

Tackling this from a different angle,
- if your web application depends on `.properties` and `.xhtml` files in order to function properly, then these files are probably not 'content'.  The fact that there is a business process that requires them to to be updated *ad hoc* does not make them content.
- 'content' is something like text, images, and videos that is added, edited and removed by an administrative user.  The application does not depend on it for correct execution, it merely reads and passes it on the browser.

Suggestions:

1. I would suggest that you deploy your application every time there is a change to the `.xhtml` or `.properties` files change.  If the editors of these files are power business users, you might think of a git push-pull tool for them and a continuous build hook, so that when they make changes and push them to the git repository, the application gets tagged with a newer version and gets built and deployed.  If there is a problem (tag not closed in xhtml), then it would be easy to roll back to the last tag.
2. Alternately, if the changes are minor (such as text descriptions), then modify the application to read them from an arbitrary external file (outside the webapp) -- a location that is provided to the webapp on startup. You can then package a 'default' version of the file in the webapp, but the code would attempt to look in the specified external location first.

Comment: What are the cons of having `.xhtml` and `.properties` files as external modifiable files outside of the WAR package?

1. will not be possible in the project environment setup. With 2. you suggest that I should make another configuration/properties file, but I do not understand the benefit of this approach.

Comment: I have added 2 paragraphs in the beginning to elaborate further.  The rule is : if your application breaks because of a malformed or corrupted xhtml or properties file -- then it is code and not content, and should go through a release cycle.  If you want to treat text as content (good!) then keep it outside the webapp and write code to read it in on loading, while providing a default version within the app so that it does not break.